# Calculate years in millis long negative answer

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying convert 14 years in millis, using function

```
    fun getMinimumAgeInMillis(): Long {
        val long: Long = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 14
        return (long)
    }
```

But instead of my value I got negative value -877631488. So, where a problem? I dont hit long limitations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use an IDE like IntelliJ, it'll hint you to the issue:

[image]

It will overflow because the types don't match. Kotlin is strict when it comes to types, and this is kinda similar to integer division, except with multiplication.

`1000` implies integer. It will autobox it to a long, but you start with an int. Related, remember how `1 / 3` != `1f / 3f`.  All you need to do is explicitly declare the type *once*. You could also do it for all, but I managed to fix it with a single one.

So instead of your current multiplication, use `1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 14`. Notice the added `L`, which converts a single type to a Long. Otherwise they default as integers, which results in an overflow that's cast to a Long.

---

If you use IntelliJ or Android Studio, try removing the explicit type. If you have those labels enabled (not entirely sure what they're called, but that's beside the point), you'll see that it shows `Int`, not `Long`:

[image]

Add `L` to one of them, and it changes to `Long` as expected. Note that the `L` needs to be added early in the multiplication. If you add it at i.e. 14, it'll overflow before it's converted to an integer. Taking `1 / 3` as an example again, `1f / 3f` is one approach, but `1 / 3f` and `1f / 3` is also valid. Basically, the types need to be correct before the "wrong" operation happens.